# How to change notification importance on android Oreo

Tags: settings

Do you have any idea about change notification importance on your android Oreo 8.0 devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on 'app & notifications', setting app-by-app.
search for 'notification' on quick-search icon (superior-right-side on app Configuration).

in another way rules of 'Do not Disturb' can do it too.

Comment: i can't find this notification importance settings on apps & notification settings in my android Oreo (Google Pixel) device. If you found any other solutions, don't forget to share with us.

Comment: "Notification Importance" option can only shows for apps that are built for Oreo (Target set to Oreo). If the app was built for previous version of Android, "Notification Importance" option cannot be shown. You may use AutoNotification app from Play Store until the app is updated to target Oreo.